# How to search field CARDS in React using React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I couldn't find how to make the field (input) work to filter the searches into cards:

can someone help me to operate the input field ?

```
**Notes.js**
```

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import NoteCard from '../components/NoteCard'
    import Masonry from 'react-masonry-css'
    import Notess from '../components/CardList'

    export default function Notes({details }) {

    const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

     const filteredNote = notes.filter(
          note => {
           return (
               note.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())   
                 );});

     const handleChange = e => {
      setSearchField(e.target.value);
             };         
     return (
       <Container>
    
          <input  type='search' onChange = {handleChange}  />
          <Notess filter={filteredNote} />

          </Container>          
        ) }
```

someone can help me to operate the input field ?

Comment: The code basically works fine, as you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-turing-flq1t?file=/src/App.js How exactly does it fail? Where are you calling `setNotes`?

Comment: You are filtering "notes" which is initialized as an empty array and I don't see you updating it anywhere in your code. Your filter function seems to be working okay. I also don't know what is the logic you use inside your "<Notess/>" component which may be relevant as well.

Comment: initially setnotes called on the component Notess:                               
export default function Notess({filter}) {
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => { fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes').then(res => res.json()).then(data => setNotes(data))}, [])
const handleDelete = async (id) => { await fetch('http://localhost:8000/notes/' +id, {      method: 'DELETE' })
const newNotes = notes.filter(note => note.id != id)
setNotes(newNotes)  }  return ( {notes.map(note => ( <div key={note.id}>            <NoteCard note={note} handleDelete={handleDelete} /></div> ))} )}

Comment: Okay but the "notes" you are filtering in your published block of code will remain empty. You are only fetching and setting the notes to a state variable inside "Notess" component. This variable has nothing to do with the one you are trying to filter.

Comment: so how can i use the variable "notes" which is inside the component Notess (already fetched), in the Notes components to be able to filter it ?

Comment: The best approach would be to declare the variable once, in the parent component ("Notes"), fetch the data there, and pass down this variable as a props to the child component ("Notess"). If for some reason you NEED to fetch the data in your child component, the child component should receive a method to update the state in the parent component once the data is fetched. But that would be more sloppy imo.

Comment: think you JuanChaher, following your approach solved my problem by fetching data in the parent component